# WPF/C# keyboard event input sendkey

Tags: c#, wpf, keyboard, sendkeys

Hi I want to type text in textbox by sendind keys from keyboard.

Xaml:

```
<Button Name="Start" Margin="20" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="Start_Click">Start</Button>
<TextBox Name="test" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2"></TextBox>
```

C#:

```
private async void Start_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
 Keyboard.Focus(test);
 await wait(1);
 SendKeys.Send("s"); 
}
```

But this gives me an error. What I made wrong ?

Comment: what error does it give? It usually says what's the problem

Comment: InvalidOperationException was unhalted by user code.

Comment: and what is the error message of the Exception?

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem is you are using "SendKeys" which is Windows Forms technology to interact with WPF components, which is not Windows Forms technology.  You need to send events to the TextBox like this:

```
TextCompositionManager.StartComposition(new TextComposition(InputManager.Current, test, "s"));
```